# Solving a function involving integrals

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I am trying to solve this equation for variable "a" in Mathematica,
this is my current attempt  However, the computation takes too long and does not give any numerical or analytical results. Can someone offer me some guidance? Greatly appreciated!

```
1.1 == 2/\[Pi] (1 + 0.2 a)^(1/2)* Integrate[Sqrt[  1/(((1 + 0.2*a)*Sin[x]^2)*(1 - a*Sin[x]^2))], {x, 0.000001, \[Pi]/
2}], a
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

I just noticed your code does not match the latex for the integrand! You wrote the integrand as

```
Sqrt[  1/(((1 + 2/10*a)*Sin[x]^2)*(1 - a*Sin[x]^2))]
```

But your Latex says it is

```
 Sqrt[  1/((1 + 2/10*a*Sin[x]^2)*(1 - a*Sin[x]^2))]
```

These are not the same.

Why did you change the integrand in code from what the Latex says?

So I deleted my old answer. Here is the new answer based on the integrand as given in the Latex, not your code:

```
integrand=Sqrt[1/((1+2/10*a*Sin[x]^2)*(1-a*Sin[x]^2))]
anti=Integrate[integrand,{x,0,Pi/2},Assumptions->a>0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But Solve can't solve it. But FindInstance can find solution

```
eq=11/10==2/π (1+2/10 a)^(1/2)*First@anti
Solve[eq,a,Assumptions->a<1]
 (*can't solve*)

FindInstance[eq,a]//N
{{a->0.284917}}
```

Same for $a<0$.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input! As I was trying to copy your codes (line 1-3 and findinstance command) into mathematica, my device couldn't evaluate, and I was not able to obtain the numerical results as you did. What could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: @Vincent I do not know why it did not work for you. May be you can add screen shot. Also make sure to start from clean kernel. Here is screen shot from my computer so you can see for yourself ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2khBB.png)  may be it is a version issue. I do not know. I know it works for me on V 13.,3